# Suggested way to retrieve Fragment managed by Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

I have fragments in a FragmentActivity, that has an ActionBar and Tab navigation. My problem is that I want to call a method on the Fragment. I cannot use findFragmentBy[Id|Tag], because the fragments are initiated and attached by the adapter, and it assigns a custom tag. I saw several solution based on keeping references to fragments, but I really want to avoid keeping any reference to my fragments, as they are handled by the FragmentPagerAdapter. Now I have everything in my Fragment (which is a workaround in my view), but the question still bothers me.

What is the best way to access a fragment instance from my activity, not added by my to FragmentManager, but the FragmentPagerAdapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by writing my own Adapter. Since they are pretty straightforward, they are easy to be implemented.